# Definition different margin for 2 sided, double sided

Tags: margins

I want to create a 2-sided article with different margins:

- front page: Left margin = 1.5 cm, right margin = 3 cm
- back page: left margin = 4 cm, right margin = 6 cm

How can I define this?

Please help. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape,left=1.5cm,right=3cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the commands `\newgeometry` and `\restoregeometry` (and `\savegeometry`) from the [**geometry**](https://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package.

But you have a `twoside` document and in twoside-mode [**geometry**](https://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) will swap left and right margins on verso pages.

You may not want this swapping with the last page of your document as it means that with the last page of your document you cannot predict whether the left margin will be 4 cm and the right margin will be 6 cm or the left margin will be 6 cm and right margin will be 4 cm as that will depend on the parity of the number of the last page of the document.

Therefore I suggest setting the LaTeX-parameters `\oddsidemargin` and `\evensidemargin`, etc, "by hand" both for the first and the last page.

Make sure these settings take place inside a local scope/within a group.

Don't use the LaTeX-commands `\setlength` and `\addtolength` etc as with these commands the assignments will in any case be global. Instead use plain-TeX-syntax.

Here is a small example.

I changed the margins in the geometry so that you can see that margins in first and last page differ from that.

In case you are interested in detalis about how to adjust margins "by hand", without using the [**geometry**](https://ctan.org/pkg/geometry)-package, the [**layout**](https://ctan.org/pkg/layout)-package might be a source of information for you.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 12pt]{article}
%\usepackage[a4paper,landscape,left=1.5cm,right=3cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[%
             a4paper,
             landscape,
             left=2cm, % I changed this from 1.5cm to 2cm so you can see that margins on 1st page differ from other margins.
             right=4.5cm,  % I changed this from 3cm to 4.5cm so you can see that margins on 1st page differ from other margins.
             top=1cm,
             bottom=1cm,
             footskip=\dimexpr(1cm-\ht\strutbox)/2+\ht\strutbox\relax % page numbers/digits usually have depth 0pt, so
                                                                      % \dp\strutbox isnot taken into account. 
                                                                      % Exception would be: old-style numbers.
           ]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{pagewidth}{}{\pagewidth=\paperwidth}%
\@ifundefined{pageheight}{}{\pageheight=\paperheight}%
\@ifundefined{pdfpagewidth}{}{\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth}%
\@ifundefined{pdfpageheight}{}{\pdfpageheight=\paperheight}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\parindent=0ex
\begingroup
% ------------------------------------------------------------
% front page: Left margin = 1.5 cm, right margin = 3 cm
% ............................................................
\textwidth=\paperwidth\relax
\advance\textwidth by -1.5cm\relax
\advance\textwidth by -3cm\relax
\linewidth=\textwidth\relax
\hsize=\textwidth\relax
\oddsidemargin=1.5cm\relax
\advance\oddsidemargin by -1in\relax
\evensidemargin=\oddsidemargin\relax
\marginparwidth=0.8cm\relax
\marginparsep=0.35cm\relax
% ............................................................
% content of front page - you must make sure yourself that 
% the material that goes into the front page does not exceed
% one page.
% ............................................................
\lipsum[1]\vfill\lipsum[2]\vfill\lipsum[3]\vfill\lipsum[4]%
\vfill\lipsum[5]\vfill\lipsum[6]\vfill\lipsum[7]%
% make sure via \newpage that the front page is shipped with
% the margins just specified:
\newpage
% Back to normal layout by ending the group:
% ------------------------------------------------------------
\endgroup

\lipsum[1]\vfill\lipsum[2]\vfill\lipsum[3]\vfill\lipsum[4]%
\vfill\lipsum[5]\vfill\lipsum[6]%
\newpage

\lipsum[1]\vfill\lipsum[2]\vfill\lipsum[3]\vfill\lipsum[4]%
\vfill\lipsum[5]\vfill\lipsum[6]%
\newpage

\begingroup
% ------------------------------------------------------------
% back page: left margin = 4 cm, right margin = 6 cm
% ............................................................
\textwidth=\paperwidth\relax
\advance\textwidth by -4cm\relax
\advance\textwidth by -6cm\relax
\linewidth=\textwidth\relax
\hsize=\textwidth\relax
\oddsidemargin=4cm\relax
\advance\oddsidemargin by -1in\relax
\evensidemargin=\oddsidemargin\relax
\marginparwidth=2cm\relax
\marginparsep=1cm\relax
% ............................................................
% content of back page - you must make sure yourself that 
% the material that goes into the back page does not exceed
% one page.
% ............................................................
\lipsum[1]\vfill\lipsum[2]\vfill\lipsum[3]\vfill\lipsum[4]%
\vfill\lipsum[5]%
% make sure via \newpage that the back page is shipped with
% the margins just specified:
\newpage
% Back to normal layout by ending the group:
% ------------------------------------------------------------
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]